# aligning memory in custom c allocator

Tags: c, memory-management, allocator

I cannot seem to find an answer to my question. I am building a memory allocator. Let's say that the user mallocs 20 bytes of memory. I am storing some memory for the header and the 20 byte payload itself.
So it looks like this

```
header | payload
```

My question is: how should I deal with memory alignment. Should I deal with it? Because, working on a 64 bit system, I would need a 4 word alignment. Should I read in this case the aligned number of bytes and give only the first 20 bytes of the payload, keep the block as not allocated and just decrease the size of it? Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: I am not sure how you want to store your header + 20 bytes in the memory when you only allocate 20 bytes

Comment: header is basically ptr next, ptr prev size and allocated bit

Comment: yes then you have to allocate memory for these pointers + 20 bytes

Comment: I would pad the header structure to be sure that the payload would start on a correct alignment, then always round the payload to an algnment multiple. This should guarantee that the current allocation and successive allocations are always correctly aligned. In case you delete one or more contigous blocks you still have aligned memory for future allocations.

Comment: "how should I deal with memory alignment. Should I deal with it?" yes, you do. The payload must be aligned to handle alignment for the most demanding type on your system. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/max_align_t for more information.

Comment: If you just make the header size (a multiple of) the max alignment, and then header+1 is also correctly aligned. You only need to worry if `sizeof(header)` is not a whole multiple of the max alignment size _and_ you really don't want to pad it for whatever reason.